# How to use Sonarqube to validate Magento 2 modules codes?

Tags: magento2

I need some guidance on below query related to sonarqube & magento 2:

How to install sonarqube?
How to validate & generate report for Magento 2 modules using sonarquobe?
I know codeSniffer being used Magento 2. Need suggestion & help on sonarqube magento 2 only.

Answer (score 0):

Please install Sonarqube server and scanner, followed by configure the scanner and add project path with SonarPHP Plugs-ins. 
**Install SonarQube server**
Download latest SonarQube from https://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/ and extract it to a folder of your choice
Start SonarQube server

#On Windows, execute:
C:\sonarqube\bin\windows-x86-xx\StartSonar.bat
#On other operating system, execute:
/etc/sonarqube/bin/[OS]/sonar.sh console

Log in to http://localhost:9000 with System Administrator credentials (admin/admin)

**Install SonarQube Scanner**
Expand the downloaded file into the directory of your choice. We’ll refer to it as  in the next steps.
Update the global settings to point to your SonarQube server by editing /conf/sonar-scanner.properties:
#----- Default SonarQube server
#sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000

Add the /bin directory to your path.
You can verify your installation by opening a new shell and executing the command sonar-scanner -h (on Windows platform the command is sonar-scanner.bat -h). You should get output like this:
usage: sonar-scanner [options]

Options:
-D,--define      Define property
-h,--help             Display help information
-v,--version          Display version information
-X,--debug            Produce execution debug output

**Configure codebase in SonarQube Scanner**

Create a configuration file in the root directory of the project: sonar-project.properties
#Configure here general information about the environment, such as SonarQube server connection details for example
#No information about specific project should appear here
#—– Default SonarQube server

sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000#—– Default source code encoding

#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8# must be unique in a given SonarQube instance
sonar.projectKey=com.:sonarqube-scanner

#this is the name and version displayed in the SonarQube UI. Was mandatory prior to SonarQube 6.1.
sonar.projectName=MyProject1
sonar.projectVersion=1.0
sonar.projectBaseDir=C:/Users//Documents/MyProjectcode/code
#Path is relative to the sonar-project.properties file. Replace “/” by “/” on Windows.
#This property is optional if sonar.modules is set.
sonar.sources=.

#Encoding of the source code. Default is default system encoding
#sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

Run the following command from the project base directory to launch the analysis:
sonar-scanner

Restart SonarQubeserver. Dashboard takes some time to refresh the latest report. It will show “In Progress” button till report gets generated.

**References** 
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/SonarPHP
https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Advanced+SonarQube+Scanner+Usages